# Is there a way to programmatically call "reload" in sbt?

Tags: sbt

Normally when sbt starts or "reload" gets invoked, sbt will emit a message "[info] Loading project definition from ..." and compile & load build.sbt if necessary.

My question is: is there a way to achieve the same thing or equivalent in a plugin using code? There doesn't seem to be a task called reload in Keys.scala so I wonder how sbt does it. Thanks.

**UPDATE:** What I want to do essentially is I want to have a build clean task that wipes out project/target and reload sbt which forces it to recompile the build config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/0.13.9/main/src/main/scala/sbt/Main.scala:

```
def doLoadProject(s0: State, action: LoadAction.Value): State =
{
      val (s1, base) = Project.loadAction(SessionVar.clear(s0), action)
      IO.createDirectory(base)
      val s = if (s1 has Keys.stateCompilerCache) s1 else registerCompilerCache(s1)
      val (eval, structure) = Load.defaultLoad(s, base, s.log, Project.inPluginProject(s), Project.extraBuilds(s))
      val session = Load.initialSession(structure, eval, s0)
      SessionSettings.checkSession(session, s)
      Project.setProject(session, structure, s)
}
```

Comment: You probably don't want to do this, though

Comment: I tried that but that didn't work, as sbt would still assume the build definition is already compiled and plugins already resolved. Command.process("reload", state.value) doesn't work either and it doesn't even emit the message so maybe it goes through a different path.

Comment: You must do it in a place where the resulting state is used. It cannot be done from a task..

Comment: Hmm maybe I'm doing it wrong. Could you take a look at my update? Otherwise that doesn't seem to be useful at all.

Comment: It cannot be a task, it must be a command. Only commands can manipulate state directly.